# Using object method affecting constructor prototype

Tags: javascript, events, constructor, prototype

If I create a new "Foo" and use the "addEventListener" method on it, it affects Foo's prototype and all new instances of Foo.

Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/TYkF2/

```
function Foo() { }

Foo.prototype = {
  _evt: { open: [], close: [] },
  addEventListener: function(name, handler) {
    if (name in this._evt) {
      if (!(this._evt[name].indexOf(handler) > -1)) {
        this._evt[name][this._evt[name].length] = handler;
      }
    }
  },
  dispatchEvent: function(name, data) {
    data = data || {};
    if (name in this._evt) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this._evt[eventName].length; i++) {
        this._evt[name][i].call(this, data);
      }
    }
  }
};

var a = new Foo();

a.addEventListener("open", function() { alert("Hey!"); });
a.dispatchEvent("open");

var b = new Foo();

b.dispatchEvent("open"); // alerts Hey

alert(Foo.prototype._evt.open); //shows a's event handler
```

Comment: I think you forgot to ask the actual question?

Comment: First paragraph :) "If I create a new "Foo" and use the "addEventListener" method on it, it affects Foo's prototype and all new instances of Foo."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `_evt: { open: [], close: [] }` is inside the prototype, `a._evt` and `b._evt` are actually the same object. If you put `_evt` in the constructor, it works as expected:

```
function Foo() {
    this._evt = { open: [], close: [] };
}
```

Comment: How would I get `this._evt` if I where to create a third variable via `Object.create(Foo.prototype)`?

Comment: Nevermind, I moved the constructors contents into a new method that makes all the objects, and made the constructor call the new method.